# Find Delta, given Epsilon $\lim_{x\to 10} \sqrt {19-x}=3, \epsilon=1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

$$\lim_{x\to 10} \sqrt {19-x}=3\\ \epsilon=1
$$

Here's what I did: $$ -1<\sqrt {19-x}-3<1 \\ 2<\sqrt {19-x}<4\\ 4 < 19-x< 16\\ -15<-x<-3\\15>x>3$$
15 is the nearest value from $x_0= 10$ $$15-10>x-10>3-10\\5>x-10>-7$$
So $\delta$ is 5

I don't if this is right though, please help?

Comment: Silly mistake $16-19=25?$

Comment: but, even then, $\delta$ would still be 5 right?

Comment: You forgot to change the $25$ in the 2nd last line

Comment: is 5 the right answer now

Comment: Once you have the inequality $3<x<15$, you know that you can choose $\delta=\min(15-10, 10-3)=5$, or any other smaller positive number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find $\delta>0$ such that the following implication holds
$$
|x-10|<\delta\Rightarrow |\sqrt{19-x}-3|<1.
$$
Note that 
$$
|\sqrt{19-x}-3|<1\ \Leftrightarrow\ 3<x<15\ \Leftrightarrow\ -7<x-10<5
$$
Therefore, for $\delta=5$ you get 
$$
|x-10|<5\ \Leftrightarrow\  -5<x-10<5\ 
\Rightarrow\ -7<x-10<5\ \Leftrightarrow\ |\sqrt{19-x}-3|<1
$$
so 
$$
|x-10|<5\Rightarrow |\sqrt{19-x}-3|<1
$$
as requared.

Comment: so $\delta = 5$?

Comment: correct, but this is not the only option, you may choose for instance $\delta=4$.

Comment: @boaz That's really the critical idea it's so hard to get students to understand when they first start proving limits rigorously-that $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are real valued variables defined in a range by inequalities. They're no different then when they had to solve equations in x and y in high school algebra and there was a parameter giving more then one possible answer. The only difference is that now instead of an exact equation with a parameter, there's an inequality that determines the range of accepted values. This is very hard to get students to understand.